# Зачем нужен List<T>, если HashSet<T> лучше?

Tags: c#

Стал замечать, что приходится менять тип коллекции с `List<T>` на `HashSet<T>` для улучшения производительности. Ну и собственно теперь кажется, что лучше я сразу буду делать HashSet-ы, везде где раньше привык делать List-ы. Или всё-таки есть ситуации, когда List предпочтительнее?

Comment: HashSet не гарантирует порядок обхода, не имеет доступа по индексу, не может содержать одинаковые элементы.

Answer (score 17):

`List<T>` - упорядоченная коллекция, которая может содержать дубликаты.

`HashSet<T>` - неупорядоченная коллекция, без дубликатов. Одно из неудобств - нужно реализовывать `GetHashCode` для элементов.

Не всегда нужно и возможно использовать `HashSet`. Хотя в случаях когда его получится использовать, будет весомый прирост производительности на больших коллекциях, так как некоторые операции выполняются быстрее (например `Contains`, `Remove`, `Add` выполняются за `O(1)`).

Comment: Может все-таки выполняются за  `O(n * log n)`?

Comment: А разве `List<T>.Add()` и `List<T>.RemoveAt()` выполняются дольше? Весь вопрос в том, нужно ли нам искать элемент в списке? Если да и часто, то `HashSet<T>` если нет или иногда, то `List<T>`

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy какая операция выполняется за `O(n log n)`?

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy `Add` за `O(1)` / `O(n)` (в зависимости от того, нужен ресайз или нет), `Contains` и `Remove` за `O(1)`. Но только если хэши элементов уникальны :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov `RemoveAt()` - `O(n)`, `Add()` - `O(1)`. Но, есть еще `Insert()`, который выполняется на `O(n)`

Comment: @Zergatul да. За `RemoveAt` согласен. Элементы еще сдвинуть нужно

Answer (score 12):

Все зависит от конкретной ситуации. Если заглянуть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), то там написано следующее:

> The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains **no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.**

Класс HashSet<T> предоставляет высокопроизводительные операции над множеством(набором). Множество(набор) - это коллекция элементов, которые не дублируются и не упорядочены.

> ...
>
> HashSet<T> implements the IReadOnlyCollection<T> interface starting with the .NET Framework 4.6; in previous versions of the .NET Framework, the HashSet<T> class did not implement this interface.

Начиная с версии .NET Framework 4.6, класс HashSet<T> реализует интерфейс IReadOnlyCollection<T>. В предыдущих версиях .NET Framework-а, этот класс не реализовывал этот интерфейс.

> ...
>
> A HashSet<T> collection **is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate elements**. **If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application**, consider using the List class together with the Sort method.

Коллекция HashSet<T> является неупорядоченной и не может содержать дубликаты. В случаях, когда наличие дубликатов или порядок элементов является более важным в вашем приложении, чем производительность, то рассмотрите возможность использования класса List<T> вместе с методом Sort.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить строго о проверке наличия элемента в коллекции (сильная сторона `HashSet<T>`), то при относительно небольших размерах коллекций линейный поиск по `List<T>` (сложность `O(n)`) будет занимать **меньше** времени, чем вызов `HashSet<T>.Contains` (сложность `O(1)`).

Comment: Почему это так?

Comment: Из-за того, что вычисление хэш-функции занимает некоторое время. Но, насколько я знаю, для всех встроенных типов реализация `GetHashCode` довольно дешевая, поэтому это актуально только для совсем уж маленьких коллекций.